# show all column values from the table

Tags: php, sql, database

I want to show the all values from table. I know i can do that with

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAMES FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE COLUMN='VALUE'
```

But it is showing just wanted values i want all columns with the SHOW COLUMN query.

I have try it like this:

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM lang
```

then it gives me all details from the `lang` table. So if i want to show lang table id = '5' like the following query

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM lang WHERE id='5'
```

then i am geting `Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause'`

Please look at the following shema it is like my table.

> I want to show for example id=5 all information like  `id, key,
>   english, turkish` ect. Why i wanted this because if i add more then
>   language like russian, germany ect. then i need to get also that
>   language information in the result.

```
+------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  id  |      key       |     english         |   turkish           |
+------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1   |       hi       |       Hi            |    Merhaba          |
+------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  2   |     profile    |      Profile        |    Profil           |
+------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+ 
|  3   |      menu      |       Menu          |     Menü            |
+------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  4   |    forgot_pass |  Forgot Password    |  Şifremi Unuttum!   |
+------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  5   |    wellcome    |      Wellcome       |   Hoş geldiniz!     |
+------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Comment: just do `SELECT * FROM lang where id = '5'`;

Comment: You need to redesign your schema, it's not relational.  You need to create three tables, ie. keys, languages and translations.  The last one will have (key_id, lang_id, translation) for each combination of key and language that you want to translate.

Answer (score 0):

Use [SELECT *](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html) instead:

```
SELECT * FROM lang where id = '5'
```

Comment: Tell me then if i add a new column then i must be change something for echo

Comment: Where is `echo` in your original problem statement ?

Comment: @Azzo select * means select all columns in table. If you add more columns later, it will select those as well.

Comment: @Paresh user wants to get all the columns

Comment: @madhur-bhaiya How can i print the query without echo. I am asking in the question with explain. I know your query i need all table information without any change after adding russian, germany ect.

Comment: @Azzo * flag will ensure that you will get all the columns from the table (always!)

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya Plase answer me if you know this think `SHOW COLUMNS FROM lang WHERE id='5'`

Comment: @Paresh If i add new columns in a table the i must be add some code in a foreach loop right ?

Comment: @Azzo You don't need to change anything. SELECT * will always select ALL columns of the table. Even after you add more columns. Just replace your existing query with the query in the above answer and it will show you all the columns every time you run it.

Comment: Never use "select *".   It's useless if you have an application that needs to work with the results and the layout of the results keep changing.

Comment: @Paresh Ok i understood i can not tell what i want exactly. No one trying to understand why i am trying to use `SHOW COLUMNS FROM lang WHERE id='5'` i know this answer and your answer. But it want to new html tags after adding new column .

Comment: @GerardH.Pille Did you undestand what i wanted exactly ? Please don't say Use: `SELECT * FROM lang where id = '5'` i know this solution. Please answer me if you have this type answer `SHOW COLUMNS FROM lang WHERE id='5'` . Like using `COLUMNS`

Comment: I said  "do NOT use select *".  Better see my comment on your question.